# Unable to compile Neo4j fdw source code

Tags: neo4j, foreign-data-wrapper

I downloaded `Neo4j fdw` source code from http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers but I'm not able to compile the source code.

Below are the errors I got, when I tried to compile:

```
Makefile:22: ../../src/Makeneo4j.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:23: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

As the error says, `src` and `contrib` directories are missing in `Neo4j FDW`.

Can you please tell me where can I get the complete code or provide more information how to compile the code ?

Comment: Could you create an issue on the repository itself? https://github.com/nuko-yokohama/neo4j_fdw/issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. You have to compile Neo4j fdw using PostgreSQL source code.

You can download the source code from the below link.

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/